# Is creating an open source github program for a undocumented api from any app/website legal?

Tags: computer-misuse-act

Recently I had an idea on creating an app from a few undocumented api i had found.

Let's suppose I created an reddit app with features and customization abilities. Is is illegal? Can I createit and make it open source (available on Github only) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is scraping a database by an undocumented API endpoint illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16581/is-scraping-a-database-by-an-undocumented-api-endpoint-illegal)

Comment: Despite the legal problems you should also be aware of practical problems. An undocumented API can change or disappear at any time.

Comment: @Philipp I'd update it. And considering if it's a big company, they wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks. Thats actually a relevant question, but there's little difference. I'm not commercially exporting it. I would update my question to fit the requirements.